# best tool for countdown?

Tags: c#

I need to start a timer and to check if it's time is elapsed. For example, at the start of my function, I give 30 seconds, then do some stuff, then wait until the 30 seconds are elapsed to go on.

I could use a `Timer`, which seems like a bazooka (the object offers way too much possibilities for what I need it) for the current situation. I could also take a `Stopwatch`, and check when it is more than 30 seconds.

However, the perfect tool if it exists would be more a combination of both: having a variable to which I set to 30 seconds, and then a property would be true/false when finished.

I know the tools mentioned above works, but for the reason explained, I wondered if there is better?

Comment: `Timer` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- To tell how long something took, use `Stopwatch`.
- To have an event fire when some time has elapsed, use `Timer`.
- To introduce a delay in an asynchronous workflow, use `await Task.Delay(x)`

The tools have been provided for you; choose the one that fits your job.

Answer (score 1):

An appropriate `Timer` (there are two in .NET BCL, pick carefully) is just fine. If you feel adventurous, try [ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.registerwaitforsingleobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I feel like this would deserve an upvote if it briefly touched on the differences between the two timers, and also mentioned why you might want to use ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject over Timer.

Comment: thanks. However for the properties is there one to see if it reached 0?